# Using a GCP service account to impersonate a Workspace user... without a key file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-workspace

I have been using a GCP service account json key file for years to impersonate a Google Workspace service account for accessing various Workspace Admin SDK APIs.

I would like to move away from having to export a key file if at all possible. My organization, for good reasons, as implemented an Org Policy to block exporting service account keys.

I would like to know how to use the Service Account running my Cloud Run service to impersonate a Workspace side Service Account please ?

PS: the service account on the Workspace side as been given `domain wide delegation` and my service account on the GCP side as been authorized against it with the necessary scopes.

PS2: I do not want to be using `gcloud` but a proper python script.

---

1. I have enabled "admin sdk"
2. I have granted "Service Account Token Creator" to the service account on the GCP side.
3. Domain Delegation is enabled on the service account on the Workspace side.
4. The GCP side service account was authorized with the necessary scopes (in my specific case, the directory API).

---

```py
import google.auth
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials


def get_access_token():

     SCOPES = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"
    ]
    # This gets the credentials of the service account running the Cloud Run service. This works without an issue.
    credentials, _project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)

    # Impersonated user's email address
    # e.g. x@y.com  in the corporate workspace org
    impersonated_user_email = WORKSPACE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL

    # Set up a Credentials object with domain-wide delegation
    target_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
        source_credentials=credentials,
        target_principal=impersonated_user_email,
        target_scopes=SCOPES
    )

    # Fetch the OIDC token with domain-wide delegation
    target_credentials.refresh(Request())
    # The above generates the "Not found; Gaia id not found for email x@y.com" exception
    access_token = target_credentials.token

    logging.debug({
        "message": f"get_access_token",
        "credentials": str(target_credentials),
        "repr(credentials)": repr(target_credentials)
    })

    return access_token
```

---

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-delegated#sa-credentials-delegated-chain), I only see delegation for GCP service accounts. I am surely missing something.

Comment: Look at my code for `Get-ComputeInstances` which calls `Impersonate-GoogleServiceAccount`. In my article about impersonation, you can see how I use one account's token to impersonate another. The code is written in PowerShell, which translates to Python very easily. https://www.jhanley.com/blog/powershell-impersonate-google-service-account/

Comment: In my code look for `delegates`. That is where you add the next identity in the chain. The REST API details are [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken).

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. Does this method work with Workspace accounts ?

Comment: I get "Gaia id not found for email ...". Sounds familiar ?

Comment: Yes, Domain Wide Delegation is supported. I need the exact error message. FYI: A user is an individual user identified by a Gaia ID. Gaia is the ID management system for all Google products. This ID may be an e-mail address associated with a Google domain (for example, user@gmail.com) or an e-mail address in another domain that has been configured by a Google Workspace domain administrator.

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not found; Gaia id not found for email x@y.com",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}

Comment: I do not see code in your post that generates that error.

Comment: As a test, modify this line to create credentials from a service account JSON key file using the same service account you have set up for ADC. `google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)`. Also, verify which credentials are being used for ADC.

Comment: This link has code to create credentials from a service account: https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation Use that method as a test to verify that the service account is set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that

```py
credentials, _project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
```

gets the GCE instance's credentials even though the Cloud Run service was deployed with a custom service account. Using the service account directly instead of the above solves the problem.

Comment: Can you post the final code that you used?